If you include an interaction between two variables, do you need to include the two variables individually as well?
Suppose I have :

Model 1: regression model with interaction effects and main effects:
$$ Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1X_1 + \beta_2X_2 + \beta_3(X_1 \times X_2) + \epsilon $$

Model 2: same regression model with only the interaction effects:
$$ Y = \beta_0 + \beta_3(X_1 \times X_2) + \epsilon $$


Is it ever appropriate to use Model 2 (i.e. omit the main effects)? I have never seen this so I am guessing no - is there a reason for this?
